# Unhandled Promise Rejection: AbortError: The operation was aborted

Tags: javascript, html

Me sale este error cuando trato de realizar un toggle de pause/play en una etiqueta de audio. El script en sí funciona pero, ¿por qué me sale ese error? Os dejo el código:

```html
<input type="button" value="No" onclick="togglePlay()">
```

```js
player = document.querySelector('audio');


function togglePlay() {
  return player.paused ? player.play() : player.pause()
}
```

¿Alguna solución?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualizo para mostrar el error con try... catch

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Envuelve tu código en un try-catch e imprime el error, esto se debe a que una función que devuelve una promesa es completada con un `reject` y no existe un catch que la maneje. Una vez que especifiques el error, tal vez podremos ayudarte más.

Comment: Hola @OscarLudick, acabo de actualizar la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probablemente `player.play()` te esté devolviendo un error y al no mostrarlo tu, lo muestra el navegador.

Prueba con esto:

```
function togglePlay() {
   return player.paused ? player.play().catch(function(err){
       console.log(err);
       elementoParaMostrarElError.textContent=err.message;
   }) : player.pause()
}
```

la parte de  `elementoParaMostrarElError` supone que tienes declarado un elemento en la pantalla para ese fin, esa línea se puede quitar si no lo tienes, pero te aconsejo agregarlo para ver. `<div id='elementoParaMostrarElError' style='color:red'></div>`, sin eso igual se puede usar F12 (o la tecla de tu navegador) para acceder a la consola y ver qué pasa.

Esto no contesta toda tu pregunta *¿por qué me sale este error?* solo te contesta *¿por qué me sale este error ahí y así?* y te puede ayudar a contestar tu pregunta (espero).

Answer (score 0):

La verdad no se que estás tratando de obtener devolviendo algo en esa función, pero el siguiente código debería funcionar correctamente.

```
function togglePlay() {
  if (player.paused) player.play(); 
    else player.pause();
}
```